# Comparing GPU accelerated encoding performance of FFMPEG v4 and v5

Tags: ffmpeg, performance, gpu

I've noticed a drop in encoding performance testing the recent FFmpeg 5.1 release with a simple full hardware transcode using `h264_nvenc` in comparison with FFmpeg 4.3/4.4.

- With FFmpeg 4.3 the transcoding takes about 92 s (last speed reported 14.3x).
- With FFmpeg 5.1 the transcoding takes about 134 s (last speed reported 9.83x).
  So the `-hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda` usage seems to result in a slower encoding.

Are there any comparable issues? Any hints to diagnose this?

**Input file**

The input.mp4 is a video with:

- Video: 21 min 51 s, H.264 (High@L3.1), 720p, 25 fps, 892 kbps
  bitrate, yuv420p
- Audio: AAC, 128 kbps, 44.1 kHz

**FFmpeg calls**

Old FFmpeg v4.3.1 version is called with parameter:

```
ffmpeg -y -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -i input.mp4 -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 2M output.mp4
```

New FFmpeg v5.1.3 version with is called parameter:

```
ffmpeg -y -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -extra_hw_frames 8 -i input.mp4 -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 2M output.mp4
```

**Build and runtime**

The test run is using ffmpeg builds created in a docker container using `nvidia/cuda:12.0.1-devel-ubuntu22.04` and `nvidia/cuda:12.0.1-base-ubuntu22.04` with `libnpp-12-0` installed as runtime image. With headers from this tag: https://github.com/FFmpeg/nv-codec-headers/archive/refs/tags/n12.0.16.0.tar.gz.

FFMPEG is build with following configuration:

```
RUN cd /tmp/ffmpeg-${FFMPEG_VERSION} && \
    ./configure \
    --prefix=${PREFIX} \
    --disable-debug \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-ffplay \    
    --enable-version3 \
    --enable-gpl \
    --enable-nonfree \
    --enable-small \
    --enable-libfdk-aac \
    --enable-openssl \
    --enable-cuda \
    --enable-cuvid \
    --enable-nvenc \    
    --enable-libnpp \
    --enable-nvenc \    
    --enable-shared \
    --extra-cflags="-I${PREFIX}/include -I${PREFIX}/include/ffnvcodec -I/usr/local/cuda/include/" \
    --extra-ldflags="-L${PREFIX}/lib -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64/" \
    --extra-libs=-ldl  && \
    make && \
    make install && \
    make distclean && \
    hash -r
```

Hardware: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080, Driver Version: 536.23, Docker 4.24.1 on Windows 10.
The performance difference was also reported from Kubernetes-based deployments.

Thanks in advance for your comments and feedback on this issue.